# Preserving normal map "extra areas"

Tags: gimp

This is what an image marked as a "normal image" looks like in Unity:

[image]

When I import this image into GIMP, this image appears like this:

[image]

I guess a big part of the image is stored in the alpha channel, and GIMP doesn't display it.

At first, I thought it was only a display problem, but when I then export it from GIMP and import it into Unity, the image looks like this:

[image]
(Yes, I have flipped it).

As one can see, the alpha channel is gone.

How could I tell GIMP to preserve it?

Thank you!

Edit: Here is some more information:
The image is a .TIFF.
If I save the edited image using "Overwrite ", then the background gets killed.
Then I try "Export as", and I choose "PNG". I leave "Save color values from transparent pixel" checked, and I leave the selection below at "Automatic pixel format". This also removes the "background".

What else could I try?

Comment: TIFF is a rather complex format, and without having a sample file it is hard to tell how exactly that additional data was stored - from the looks of the channels dialog in your screenshot, it seems that the data in the transparent areas wasn't even imported. Can you share a sample TIFF file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you are exporting the image back from GIMP - but if you use the `export as...` dialog, upon choosing to export to .png, there is a `save color values from transparent pixels` checkbox.
Just check it before confirming the export.

(It won't show if you just click on `export to NAME` to write the same image back - you have to do  `export as...` and select the same name for the dialog to apear).

Also, it is not that `part of the image is stored in the alpha channel` The alpha channel just contains opacity data - in this case, it contains a maks for regions of  full-opacity/full-transparency for the shown region. GIMP's normal saving mechanism will erase the color data in the fully transparent areas to save image size upon exporting.

If you are using other image formats than PNG, GIMP does not have the option to preserve the data in transparent areas - the workarounds would be exporting to PNG and then converting to PNG with another tool (which might or not preserve these data), or raising the alpha-channel values to "1" instead of "0" before exporting in GIMP (can be done with `colors->levels` or `colors->curves`)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that. I have edited my post and explained what I have tried additionally. So far nothing helped. Can you have a look at my edit?